# how to print colors names in C without files or arrays?

Tags: c

Hey how are you? I want to ask if there is any way in C language to print the colors names without being stored in arrays or files.....like we put the code of the a specific color and the program will print White e.g for #FFFFFFF or something like that??
I want a huge number of colors names in my project

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122986/is-it-ok-to-leave-what-have-you-tried-comments) Context would be immensely helpful.

Comment: You mean something like [that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1) but for `C` and preferably portable?

Comment: Wonder if you have thought of using "enum" and "switch" for meeting your purpose? FYI: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/whbyts4t.aspx

Comment: You don't print color names or colors in standard C (because standard C does not have any notion of color). You need to be more specific, and tell about your operating system, compiler, running environment, libraries....

Comment: BTW, most of web colors in web notations have no names. Only a few hundreds (see [HTML color names](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colornames.asp)) out of 2^24 have a "name".

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to calculate what colour something is - e.g. something with dominant red + blue becomes "purple", much "red" and not much in the others is "red" and if it's high levels it's "light" and if the levels are "low" it's dark. But there is still a huge number of combinations of colours, and not every one of the 16777216 colours that you can combine from the HTML colours can be called a name.

If we call 808080 as "medium gray", what do you call 818181 and 7f7f7f that are nearly identical?

(And "without using arrays", that probably makes this almost impossible - of course, we can make "code-tables" instead of "arrays", e.g. using a switch or long chain of if-statements, but if you are making no calculations in the process, you are just letting the compiler build a table for you, instead of using an array in the first place)

Here's a bit of code that names a colour - it is far from perfect, but it may give you some idea... I've tried to achieve something that has some flexibility. There are other ways that you could achieve something similar. But it's a quick stab, and I'm sure if I spent another few hours on it, and had some meaningful input data [I'm lacking the imagination to come up with colours...]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct tColourDef
{
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;
    const char *colour;
} ColourDef;


// Portion up the colours in 1/8 of the range, 0-7. 

static ColourDef baseColours[] = 
{
    { 0, 0, 0, "Unknown" },
    { 0, 0, 0, "Black" },
    { 7, 7, 7, "White" },
    { 7, 0, 0, "Red" },
    { 0, 7, 0, "Green" },
    { 0, 0, 7, "Blue" },
    { 7, 7, 0, "Yellow" },
    { 4, 4, 4, "Gray" },
    { 7, 0, 4, "Pink" },
    { 5, 2, 0, "Brown" },
    { 7, 0, 5, "Magenta" },
    { 0, 7, 7, "Cyan" },
    { 4, 0, 4, "Purple" },
    { 7, 3, 0, "Orange" },
    { 4, 0, 0, "Maroon" },
    { 5, 0, 7, "Violet" },
    { 2, 6, 6, "Turqoise" },
};

#define NCOLOURS (sizeof baseColours/sizeof baseColours[0])

inline int iabs(int x)
{
    if (x < 0) return -x;
    return x;
}

int FindColour(int r, int g, int b, char *buffer, size_t buffer_size)
{
    int i;
    // Shift colour down... 
    r >>= 5;
    g >>= 5;
    b >>= 5;
    int smallestError = 5;   // Bigger than this, and we say "unknown".
    int bestIndex = 0;       // Point at "unknown"
    for(i = 1; i < NCOLOURS; i++)
    {
        int error;
        error = abs(r - baseColours[i].r) +
            abs(b - baseColours[i].b) + 
            abs(g - baseColours[i].g);
        if (error < smallestError && error < 3)
        {
            smallestError = error;
            bestIndex = i;
        }
    }
    strncpy(buffer, baseColours[bestIndex].colour, buffer_size);
    return (bestIndex > 0);
}


int main()
{
    int testColours[] = { 0xFF0000, 
                          0x00FF00, 
                          0x0000FF, 
                          0x008080, 
                          0x808080,
                          0x770000,
                          0xf01780,
                          0x333333,
    };
    int i; 
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof testColours / sizeof testColours[0]; i++)
    {
        int r = testColours[i] >> 16;
        int g = (testColours[i] >> 8) & 0xff;
        int b = testColours[i] & 0xff;
        char buffer[30];
        int res = FindColour(r, g, b, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        printf("%02x:%02x:%02x = %s\n", r, g, b, buffer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [X-Macros](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Preprocessor#X-Macros):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define COLORS_RGB \
  COLOR_ENTRY(white, 0xffffff) \
  COLOR_ENTRY(black, 0x000000) \
  COLOR_ENTRY(red, 0xff0000) \
  COLOR_ENTRY(green, 0x00ff00) \
  COLOR_ENTRY(blue, 0x0000ff)

#define STR(x) #x

char* get_color_name_rgb(unsigned int color) {
    switch(color) {
#define COLOR_ENTRY(name,value) case value: return STR(name);
    COLORS_RGB
#undef COLOR_ENTRY
    default: return "unknown color";
    };
}

int main ()
{
    unsigned int colors[] = {0xffffff, 0xff0000, 0x00ff00,
                             0x0000ff, 0x000000, 0x123456};
    size_t ncolors = sizeof(colors)/sizeof(*colors);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < ncolors; i++)
        printf("value: 0x%06x, name: %s\n",
               colors[i], get_color_name_rgb(colors[i]));
}
```

The output is:

```
$ gcc test.c && ./a.out
value: 0xffffff, name: white
value: 0xff0000, name: red
value: 0x00ff00, name: green
value: 0x0000ff, name: blue
value: 0x000000, name: black
value: 0x123456, name: unknown color
```